# why need to escape string in html?

Tags: html, sql

Well, I know that "correct" escaping will help to prevent SQL injection.

But I saw people escaping values in HTML

```
<input type="text" value =/"some/" /> <!-- some escaped, why? -->
```

Question is:
Why to escape in HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `<input type="text" value =/"some/" /> <!-- some escaped, why? -->`

That is a syntax error. Don't do that.

Use [character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.3) to represent special characters (`&amp;`, `&lt;`, etc).

> Why to escape in HTML?

(Assuming you use the correct syntax to do so): because some characters have special meaning in HTML. For example, you don't want a `"` (in the data) ending your attribute value prematurely since that can:

- Lose data
- Lose data but have it display in the page
- Allow third parties to [inject their JavaScript into your pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and steal data / redirect people to phishing sites / etc

Comment: @Quetin thanks for the answer. But what do you mean (just bit confused) by losing data? Value of input? or what?

Comment: If you have `value="foo"bar"` then the control will only have `foo` in the data, `"bar` will be lost.